# My QT app.exe was unable to start 0x00007b

Tags: c++, qt

i recently made a program with QTCreator however everytime i try to launch the .exe it says i need some DLL's then after i put the DLL's in the folder it gives me "The Application was unable to start 0x00007b" . The .exe works when im compiling in QT however it doesn't seem to work when i try to launch it directly from its folder .

I already installed Visual studio , directX but still nothing.

Also is it possible to remove the dependency from the DLL's so my .exe's can work on any computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have dynamically linked you application so it needs to find the Qt libraries in order to use the framework. When launched from Qt creator, the application environment is correct and has all required dependencies in the path. When launched standalone, your environment probably does not have the correct PATH setup.

You may want to investigate the [deployment tool for windows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) which will help you find some of your dependencies. The same page also discusses your options with regards to building a static version of your program.

Comment: i have to ask , even when i deploy my app it does copy some DLL's that take a lot of memory considering how small my program is. what i want is for it to take the minimum amount of memory :/.

Comment: If your mainly problem is the space taken by icu dlls, read about "minimal icu" on google.